# Using an RCT and a retrospective cohort in the same study

Tags: clinical-trials, random-allocation, case-cohort

I have seen that in RCT’s with very long follow up times the power of the study can be impacted by various factors in Herbet, Kasza, and Bø, 2018, and I was wondering if anyone has heard of comparing an RCT that has a long follow up time with a retrospective cohort study which could be designed to decrease loss of information due to follow up issues (I’m not talking about death/non- adherence or anything that could be associated with the trial, but random events such as moving out of a study population etc).

Would it be interesting to compare to see if the results were different?

Herbert, R. D., Kosza, J., and Bø, K. (2018). [Analysis of randomised trials with long-term follow-up](https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12874-018-0499-5). *BMC Medical Research Methodology*. *18*(48).

Comment: You might want to look for articles by M. Zelen about "double randomized consent" trials where participants are randomized to something like an RCT, and to something like a cohort design, and where differential drop out accounts for some of the selection bias in who agrees to participate in an RCT. For a review see Altman, D. G., Whitehead, J., et al. (1995). Randomised consent designs in cancer clinical trials. *European Journal of Cancer*, 31(12), 1934-1944.